# remove double spaces and replace them with a single one

Tags: batch-file

I need to remove empty spaces from a command executed.

I use `set /p` to get the variable.

If the user enters:

```
------what-----is---------my--------ip---------
```

...where `------` are empty spaces, I want to have the following result:

```
what is my ip
```

(There's only one space between the words)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple native batch command that can do exactly what you want. Batch is fairly weak when it comes to text manipulation. But it can be done with a small block of native batch code.

Here is one pure batch solution. The code replaces double space with single space in a loop until no more double spaces exist. Then it removes any leading and trailing space. I chose to use delayed expansion because that eliminates problems with special characters like `&` `<` `>` etc.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str="
set /p "str=Enter a string: "
echo before: '!str!'

:: **** Begin space compression code ****
:loop
if defined str (
  set "new=!str:  = !"
  if "!new!" neq "!str!" (
    set "str=!new!"
    goto :loop
  )
)
if defined str if "!str:~0,1!" equ " " set "str=!str:~1!"
if defined str if "!str:~-1!" equ " " set "str=!str:~0,-1!"
:: **** End space compression code ****

echo after:  '!str!'
```

There are various utilities that you could download to make the job easier. For example, the free [Gnu sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) could make short work of the problem.

Some offices do not allow use of downloaded executables. I have written a hybrid JScript/batch script named REPL.BAT that is very useful for text manipulation. It provides convenient regular expression search and replace functionality, and it uses only native Windows commands, and doesn't require any installation. So it should be OK to use just about anywhere.

Here is a solution that uses the REPL.BAT utility. It is much shorter than the pure batch solution above, and it does not need delayed expansion. (I do temporarily enable delayed expansion just to reliably echo the value)

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "str="
set /p "str=Enter a string: "

call :displayValue "before:" str

:: **** Begin space compression code ****
for /f "eol= tokens=* delims= " %%A in (
  'repl "  *" " " s str ^| repl " $" ""'
) do set "str=%%A"
:: **** End space compression code ****

call :displayValue "after: " str
exit /b


:displayValue
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo %~1 '!%~2!'
exit /b
```

The first REPL command reads the environment variable and converts consecutive spaces into a single space. That result is piped into a second REPL command that removes any trailing space. Finally, the output of that is processed by the FOR /F command that removes leading spaces.

Here is the REPL.BAT utility that the above code relies on. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Documentation ***********
:::
:::REPL  Search  Replace  [Options  [SourceVar]]
:::REPL  /?
:::
:::  Performs a global search and replace operation on each line of input from
:::  stdin and prints the result to stdout.
:::
:::  Each parameter may be optionally enclosed by double quotes. The double
:::  quotes are not considered part of the argument. The quotes are required
:::  if the parameter contains a batch token delimiter like space, tab, comma,
:::  semicolon. The quotes should also be used if the argument contains a
:::  batch special character like &, |, etc. so that the special character
:::  does not need to be escaped with ^.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /? then prints help documentation
:::  to stdout.
:::
:::  Search  - By default this is a case sensitive JScript (ECMA) regular
:::            expression expressed as a string.
:::
:::            JScript syntax documentation is available at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Replace - By default this is the string to be used as a replacement for
:::            each found search expression. Full support is provided for
:::            substituion patterns available to the JScript replace method.
:::            A $ literal can be escaped as $$. An empty replacement string
:::            must be represented as "".
:::
:::            Replace substitution pattern syntax is documented at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/efy6s3e6(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Options - An optional string of characters used to alter the behavior
:::            of REPL. The option characters are case insensitive, and may
:::            appear in any order.
:::
:::            I - Makes the search case-insensitive.
:::
:::            L - The Search is treated as a string literal instead of a
:::                regular expression. Also, all $ found in Replace are
:::                treated as $ literals.
:::
:::            E - Search and Replace represent the name of environment
:::                variables that contain the respective values. An undefined
:::                variable is treated as an empty string.
:::
:::            M - Multi-line mode. The entire contents of stdin is read and
:::                processed in one pass instead of line by line. ^ anchors
:::                the beginning of a line and $ anchors the end of a line.
:::
:::            X - Enables extended substitution pattern syntax with support
:::                for the following escape sequences:
:::
:::                \\     -  Backslash
:::                \b     -  Backspace
:::                \f     -  Formfeed
:::                \n     -  Newline
:::                \r     -  Carriage Return
:::                \t     -  Horizontal Tab
:::                \v     -  Vertical Tab
:::                \xnn   -  Ascii (Latin 1) character expressed as 2 hex digits
:::                \unnnn -  Unicode character expressed as 4 hex digits
:::
:::                Escape sequences are supported even when the L option is used.
:::
:::            S - The source is read from an environment variable instead of
:::                from stdin. The name of the source environment variable is
:::                specified in the next argument after the option string.
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
if .%2 equ . (
  if "%~1" equ "/?" (
    findstr "^:::" "%~f0" | cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "^:::" ""
    exit /b 0
  ) else (
    call :err "Insufficient arguments"
    exit /b 1
  )
)
echo(%~3|findstr /i "[^SMILEX]" >nul && (
  call :err "Invalid option(s)"
  exit /b 1
)
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b 0

:err
>&2 echo ERROR: %~1. Use REPL /? to get help.
exit /b

************* JScript portion **********/
var env=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var search=args.Item(0);
var replace=args.Item(1);
var options="g";
if (args.length>2) {
  options+=args.Item(2).toLowerCase();
}
var multi=(options.indexOf("m")>=0);
var srcVar=(options.indexOf("s")>=0);
if (srcVar) {
  options=options.replace(/s/g,"");
}
if (options.indexOf("e")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/e/g,"");
  search=env(search);
  replace=env(replace);
}
if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/l/g,"");
  search=search.replace(/([.^$*+?()[{\\|])/g,"\\$1");
  replace=replace.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$");
}
if (options.indexOf("x")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/x/g,"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
    function($0,$1,$2){
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
    }
  );
  replace=replace.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
}
var search=new RegExp(search,options);

if (srcVar) {
  WScript.Stdout.Write(env(args.Item(3)).replace(search,replace));
} else {
  while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
    if (multi) {
      WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll().replace(search,replace));
    } else {
      WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().replace(search,replace));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dbenham, thats exactly what i needed.  Can you please explain me how this two lines work - if defined str if "!str:~0,1!" equ " " set "str=!str:~1!" - if defined str if "!str:~-1!" equ " " set "str=!str:~0,-1!"   thanks

Comment: @user2086682 - Those lines remove any leading and trailing space. The IF DEFINED bit is to protect against undefined variables (empty strings). The remainder uses simple environment variable substring operations. Type `HELP SET` or `SET /?` from the command prompt for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P x=
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('ECHO %x%') DO SET y=%%i
ECHO original input  : %x%
ECHO spaces condensed: %y%
```

For an input string

```
      What     is         my        ip
```

This returns

```
original input  :       What     is         my        ip
spaces condensed: What is my ip
```

Comment: +1, Very interesting approach to let the command parser compress the spaces. However, it also converts any combination of consecutive `<tab>` `,` `;` `=` and `<space>` into a single `<space>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I soleved it (uses delayed expansion):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
SET /P str=
for /l %%i in (1,1,31) do set str=!str:  = !
ECHO spaces condensed: !str!
```

I make substitution of two consecutive spaces with one in a loop - lets say you have string with 8 spaces. Then it becomes:

```
1        1
1    1
1  1
1 1
```

I know it is not universal, but works well enough (up to 2^31 spaces). To deal with leading spaces you can use this trick (found on www.dostips.com):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("!str!") do set str=%%a
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but this is the way I prefer to do this:

```
@ECHO OFF
:retry
ECHO.

SET str=
SET /P str=Type text here: 
IF NOT DEFINED str GOTO retry

:: remove double spaces
:remove_double_spaces
IF NOT "%str%" == "%str:  =%" SET str=%str:  = %&& GOTO remove_double_spaces

:: retry if nothing but spaces
IF "%str%" == " " GOTO retry

:: remove leading space
IF "%str:~0,1%" == " " SET str=%str:~1%

:: remove trailing space
IF "%str:~-1%" == " " SET str=%str:~0,-1%

ECHO "%str%"
GOTO retry
```